# form submission prevent return button from being pressed but bind to function

Tags: php, ajax, forms

I have a form which is being posted via ajax. I would like the default action of the return button on the keyboard removed and replaced by the .click event.

here is my code posting the **form:**

```
$("#submit").click(function(){
var name = $("#name").val();

if(name ==''|| email==''|| contact==''|| gender==''|| msg==''){
//alert("Insertion Failed Some Fields are Blank....!!");
}
else{

$.post("<?php bloginfo('template_url');?>/ajax.php",{ name1: name, email1: email, contact1: contact, gender1:gender, msg1:msg},
 function(data) {

 $('#form')[0].reset(); //To reset form fields
 });

 }
});
```

I have then got the following to prevent the reurn key being **pressed:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).keydown(function(event){
    if(event.keyCode == 13) {
      event.preventDefault();
      return false;
    }
  });
});
```

any idea on how i would achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your function when the return key gets pressed:

```
$(window).keydown(function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $("#submit").click();
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

call the click method of the submit button.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $(window).keydown(function(event){
  if(event.keyCode == 13) {
   $("#submit").click();
   event.preventDefault();
   return false;
  }
 });
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/click/#example-1